# verbatim inside macro with color

Tags: color, verbatim

Consider the following minimal non-working example (comment the line with the `\test{..}` to compile. I'd like to have a `\verb+something+` inside my `\test{}` environment. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
This works \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+ 

\test{This is a test of a \verb+verb+}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't place `\verb` inside a macro definition, or as an argument to one.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can't as in "that's not even slightly possible"?

Comment: Correct, but there are other ways to skin the cat, depending on the requirements.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I love to skin cats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use `cprotect`, but you should think twice before using `\verb` when, perhaps`,`\texttt` might suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,cprotect}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\begin{document}

This works \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+

\cprotect\test{This is a test of a \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have several appearances of `\test` containing `\verb`, you might want to make it automatically apply `\cprotect`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,cprotect}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\cMakeRobust\test

\begin{document}

This works \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+

\test{This is a test of a \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Was unaware of `\cprotect`.  That's pretty cool.

Comment: `\texttt{}` could suffice, but it would make it a nightmare to write something code-ish in the macro...

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, `\verb` can neither appear in a macro definition nor argument.

However, depending on your need, this may suffice.  One saves a `verbbox` in advance, and can pass that as an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
This works \verb+\num{6.022e-23}+ 

\begin{verbbox}verb\end{verbbox}%
\test{This is a test of a \theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the verb in blue, then the `verbbox` can be saved as `{\color{blue}\begin{verbbox}verb\end{verbbox}}%`.