# Trying to colorize `...` content in markdown, I have used \texttt in a command. It's not perfect: -- are displayed joined, like a single minus sign

Tags: macros, text-decorations

I've attempted to create a command so that a ` `--namespace=<mon-namespace>` ` in markdown would produce the same fixed font, but colorized

changing this:

```
qui est accessible en ajoutant `--namespace=<mon-namespace>` à une commande `kubectl`.
```

by that:

```
qui est accessible en ajoutant \fonction{--namespace=<mon-namespace>} à une commande `kubectl`.
```

where `\fonction` has this definition in markdown `header-includes:`

```
\newcommand{\mauve}[1]{\textcolor{Purple}{#1}}
\newcommand{\fonction}[1]{\begingroup\small\mauve{\texttt{#1}}\endgroup}
```

**The result is nearly what I'm willing to have, but not exactly.** Here's a capture of its pdf result, below:

[image]

the two minus signs `--` preceding `namespace` look like they are only one, and this is  trouble prone.

It seems that `\texttt` should not be the *Latex* function, or not the only function, I should use to achieve the result I'm willing.

What should I change in my function
`\newcommand{\fonction}[1]{\begingroup\small\mauve{\texttt{#1}}\endgroup}`
for that?

Comment: Did you try `\verb+#1+` instead of `\texttt{#1}`?

Comment: I'm trying: `\newcommand{\fonction}[1]{\begingroup\small\mauve{\verb+#1+}\endgroup}`, but I'm receiving a LaTeX Error: `\verb illegal in command argument.`

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not specific for Markdown but I think at least some of the approaches would be applicable for your situation.

Comment: An approach with verbatim could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304334/verbatim-inside-macro-with-color. Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370334/use-color-in-verbatim-environment may be useful.

Comment: @Marijn Well, I used the `\usepackage{microtype}` with `\DisableLigatures[-]{}` trick, that looked the less disruptive, and it worked, thanks a lot! But I wonder how the text between ticks, with markdown, does itself to achieve that result of not any ligatures. Do you think it disable them, also?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I don't know exactly how that works in Markdown but I suspect that backticks are a shortcut for `\verb`, which indeed displays all characters exactly as they are entered without further processing (i.e., verbatim).